# Returning multiple values from function

Tags: go

I have this function:

```
func GetBasicAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    secret, _, ok := r.BasicAuth()
    if !ok {
        return "", err //is this right?
    }
    return secret, nil
}
```

I've had to declare that the function will return a string and an error but in reality it will return one or the other. If the BasicAuth function wasn't `ok` then I have no string to return so what do I do here - just send an empty string? This seems weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless documented otherwise (e.g. `io.Reader`),
it's normal for Go functions/methods returning `a, b, c, …, error` to expect that if `err != nil` that all other returned values are undefined and should not be used/examined.
It's usual (but not required) that when returning an error
the function/method uses whatever [the zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) is for those other return values.

As mentioned, some functions/methods such as an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)'s `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` explicitly state other behaviour:

> Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before
>   considering the error err.

And any functions/methods you create that return useful values even in the case of (some) errors should probably explicitly state that.